# What's the best strategy for managing PEAR and include path?

Tags: php, include, pear

I need this to work in different environments, and PEAR might be installed in different locations; at the moment, I'm relying on the `include_path` to take care of that. However, a naive include of a PEAR library is dangerous:

```
include "Mail.php";
```

since I may have a "Mail.php" (or "mail.php"* ...) library in the current directory. I'm guessing I could set a constant in each environment (e.g. `PEAR_PATH`) and use an absolute path, e.g.

```
include PEAR_PATH."/Mail.php";
```

which also has the benefit of indicating where Mail.php comes from! Is that the strategy others use? Ideally, I wouldn't duplicate that value, but I guess if I'm only ever including files with a full absolute path, that shouldn't be an issue.

Alternatively, I *could* do some up-front parsing of the include_path, determine where the file is ... this is basically just recreating the 'search the include path' behaviour of `include`, which seems silly!

* I now realise that this depends on the case-sensitivity of the filesystem; one of my environments is a Mac.

Comment: The docs are very useful indeed: http://pear.php.net/manual/en/installation.checking.php

Comment: @Stuart I don't see how that page answers my question ...

Comment: You did read it right!? It will help you discover where PEAR is installed so you can get the correct path.

Comment: Yup. I don't see a method for determining where PEAR is installed, from PHP. Are you suggesting I do something like `exec("pear config-get php_dir")`?

Answer (score -1):

PEAR relies on the correct setup of PHP's include path. You as server administrator have to take care of this. The docs say so: http://pear.php.net/manual/en/installation.checking.php#installation.checking.cli.modifyingphpini

PHP files in PEAR packages have many `require_once 'Path/File.php';` calls in them; you can't and should not change them. This is the reason you should not have the same file names in your local project directory.

The best way to prevent duplicate-filepath problems is to use a [PSR-0](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-0/) compatible directory structure, and a namespace for your project classes.

Comment: Yup, I have the include path setup correctly. What about the question?